# Prevent overflow errors when multiplying and powering in Python

Tags: python, numeric, multiplication, limits

How would you prevent the errors when calling function biased_random defined below and what are the limits for arguments `scale` and `bias` to hold for preventing problems with big or small numbers?

```
def biased_random(scale, bias):
  return random.random() ** bias * scale

>>> sum(biased_random(1000, 10) for x in range(100)) / 100
64.94178302276364

>>> sum(biased_random(1000, 100000) for x in range(100)) / 100
0.0

>>> sum(biased_random(1000, 0.002) for x in range(100)) / 100
998.0704866851909
```

Comment: This seems clearly defined here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format.  This defines the limits on floating-point numbers.  10**308 is pretty clearly defined as the upper limit.  Is this what you're looking for?  What more do you need to know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `sys.maxint` to figure out what the overflow point is. Then divide or nth-root it and compare with the number that you have:

```
r = random.random()
if sys.maxint ** (1.0/bias) < r:
    print "overflow imminent"
elif sys.maxint/float(scale) < r ** bias:
    print "overflow imminent"
else:
    print "overflow unlikely. To infinity, and beyond..."
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Figure out what the overflow on your machine is (should be `sys.maxint`). Then you can test away. What I've posted is an implementation of a theoretic discussion I had with someone, some time back

Comment: I'm testing it and seems that it works (in accordance to limit 10**308 as S.Lott commented), but wonder how you solved it in the theoretical discussion.

Comment: It was algebra. What you want to do is test that `x * c` (where `c` is a constant) will not overflow. You know (or can easily find) the overflow value. Then you do `overflow/c` if `x` is bigger than this number, then you're headed for an overflow.